# jquery "SyntaxError: Unexpected token y"

Tags: jquery

This is probably a trivial question but I've been looking for the past couple of days with no solution. I am making an ajax call like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "results",
    dataType: 'json',
})
.fail( function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
    })
    .done(function(data){   
        $.each(data.myitems, function(index, item){
          // do stuff here  
        });
    });
```

My json looks like this:

```
{
"thisvariable":1,
"anothervariable":2,
    "myitems":[
        {"name":"Matt",
        "birthday":"1978-02-23 00:00:00"},
        {"name":"Carol\y",
        "birthday":"1967-05-05 00:00:00"},
        {"name":"Bob",
        "birthday":"1984-02-03 00:00:00"}
        ]
}
```

When I make this call, I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token y". It doesn't like the backslash in Carol\y. This data is coming from a mysql database.

Comment: Have you tried adding a backslash in front of the first one - i.e., `Carol\\y`?

Comment: Why is the y being escaped? Shouldn't be necessary... can you post the code that is generating the JSON?

Comment: this is just an example. Don't assume Carol\y is the real data

Comment: Try pasting that JSON into jsonlint.com - it will flag the "Carol\y" as invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever is creating the JSON on the server side, should be properly escaping the backslash: `Carol\\y`.

If you can't control how the JSON is created, maybe you could intercept it and replace occurrences of `'\'` with `'\\'` before it makes it back to the client.

Comment: (Or perhaps just `Caroly` or `Carol` or zomg-where-did-that-come-from .. but it is indeed invalid JSON and an invalid EMCAScript string literal value .. +1)

Comment: @Dan: How would I intercept it?

Comment: That would depend on several things.  What server-side technology are you using?  Where are the MySql query results being converted to JSON?  I'd love to help you, but without seeing more of your code, I can't.

Comment: @pst...why is it invalid JSON?